# multiple joins for different ids in same and different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I've different tables and I've to fetch data.

```
order table

orderId, clientId, buyerId, loadingCompanyId, productTypeId, orderStatusId

user table

userId, userCompanyName

orderStatus table

orderStatusId, orderStatusName,

productType table

productTypeId, productTypeName
```

so I've these tables. In order table clientId, buyerId and loadingCompanyId are coming from user's table userId and I want to fetch its userCompanyName, orderStatusId is coming from orderStatus table and I want to fetch orderStatusName and last one is productTypeName productTypeId is coming from productType table and want to fetch productTypeName but the problem is with clientId, buyerId and loadingCompanyId these three ids are userId from user table so how I've to fetch client, buyer and loading company names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That are some simple joins with aliases

```
select * 
from order 
join user client on clientId = client.userId
join user buyer on buyerId = buyer.userId
join user company on loadingCompanyId = company.userId
join orderStatus  on orderStatus.orderStatusId= order.orderStatusId
join productType on productType.productTypeId = order.productTypeId
```

Comment: so what about buyerId and loadingCompanyId?

Comment: `from order join user client` order is table but what is client? Is it aliases of user?

Comment: @user3833682 client is an alias for the table user. Read [here}(http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) for more information about `aliasses`in SQL.

Comment: Your query showing same companies name in client, buyer and loading company.

Comment: @user3833682 no it cannot be if the clientId, buyerId  and loadingCompanyId are different. The company name of loading company is `company.userCompanyName` the client company is `client.userCompanyName`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT O.orderId, UserClient.userCompanyName As clientName, UserBuyer.userCompanyName AS buyerName, UserloadingCompany.userCompanyName AS buyerName, OS.orderStatusName, PT.productTypeName
FROM Order O
INNER JOIN user AS UserClient
ON O.clientId = UserClient.userId
INNER JOIN user AS UserBuyer
ON O.buyerId = UserBuyer.userId
INNER JOIN user AS UserloadingCompany
ON O.loadingCompanyId = UserloadingCompany.userId
INNER JOIN orderStatus AS OS
ON O.orderStatusId = OS.orderStatusId
INNER JOIN productType AS PT
ON O.productTypeId = PT.productTypeId
```

Comment: where is loadingCompanyId?

Comment: I have edited my answer.  please check. Edited below lines
INNER JOIN user AS UserBuyer
ON O.buyerId = UserBuyer.userId
INNER JOIN user AS UserloadingCompany
ON O.loadingCompanyId = loadingCompany.userId